# Create table in SQL Server that support multilingual collation

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, non-ascii-characters, nvarchar

```
alter column party_name nvarchar(max)
```

I am trying to insert below characters:

```
insert into landing.lnd_test (party_name)
values ('성 이름')
```

but in the table I see the values are replaced with `'? ??'`.

How do I alter this column so I can see correct data?

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18

Comment: You need to **prefix** the string literal in your `INSERT` statement with `'N'` to indicate **Unicode** characters: `insert into landing.lnd_test (party_name) values (N'성 이름')`

Comment: Hi, Like this iam able to add manually, but currently iam loading the data from the file into the table. How can i define this in the table : alter column party_name nvarchar(max)  - if i do this and load from the file -it is not working.

Comment: `nvarchar` is by definition multilingual. Collations affect how strings are ordered in indexes and `ORDER BY` clauses, they don't affect the (non-existent) codepage of the nvarchar field

Comment: How do you import the text? The collation has nothing to do with the lost data. This is a problem caused by loading non-Unicode text using the wrong codepage. This is 100% a problem of the tool you use to import the file

Comment: If you use the Import Data wizard in SSMS you need to specify the correct file codepage in the *source*. The import task will convert the text to Unicode based on that. Check the [list of Windows codepages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/code-page-identifiers). There are several Korean codepages.

Comment: PS: This very question proves Unicode works without modifying collations. Stack Overflow is a .NET application storing Unicode strings to `nvarchar` columns. That's why you could type `'성 이름'` in your question and I can type `Αυτό Εδώ` in the very same field and yet, both appear just fine

Comment: Hi, yeah i added the column as nvarchar. and the tool i was using to import the data from file to sql table there i have set the useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=utf8 and it is working now .

Answer (score 0):

Agreed to @Panagiotis Kanavos' comment, when importing data from flat file, if encoding is UTF8, `성 이름` is copied to SQL and displayed as is.

I tried giving many encoding options, while using data factory to import flat file data. UTF-8 encoding gave the data as in source.

[image]

- When different encoding is given, output looks like
  [image]
- When **UTF-8** is given, the output looks like
  [image]