# How to apply trim logic to multilingual characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, non-ascii-characters

I am trying to use below query:

```sql
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(TRIM([dbo].[fn_string_shuffle] (a.text_field)),'&#x20;',' '),'&amp;','&') AS [text_field] from dbo.test;
```

`a.text_field` has value `성 이름` but after this function it is converting to `" ???"`

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Output every step and see where it goes wrong, e.g. do `select [dbo].[fn_string_shuffle], trim([dbo].[fn_string_shuffle]), ...`.

Comment: while trimming itself TRIM([dbo].[fn_string_shuffle] (a.text_field)) it gives "?&#x20;??"  - it has added '?' while trimming itself

Comment: iam using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18

Comment: SSMS 18 isn't an RDBMS, it's an IDE like application. What RDBMS  and version are you using here? For example SQL Server 2017, Azure SQL Database.

Comment: I suspect the *real* problem is your (scalar) user-defined function `fn_string_shuffle`. I suggest taking the time here to create a [mre].

Comment: Without the definition of the function (which we can't guess what it does), this is not reproducible: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kwm2UWPF)

Comment: You already asked about mangled Korean characters. The problem isn't Korean, it's how you import the text.  You still haven't explained that. `&#x20;` isn't even Korean, it's a weird way of HTML encoding a single space character. The [*normal* way is `&nbsp;`](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp). Someone though they should use the entity number, `&x20;`. If you managed to import the text properly, the problem is then `fn_string_shuffle` which somehow converts Unicode back to an ASCII codepage , once again mangling the text

Comment: Make sure you are using NVARCHAR and NCHAR, and not VARCHAR or CHAR in your function and in all your fields (columns).

Comment: Again, and again, this very question proves there's absolutely no problem with Unicode. That's why you were able to type `성 이름` in the question and I can type `Αυτό Εδώ`. SO stores text in `nvarchar` fields. No text was mangled. No special encoding was used

Comment: Based on the OP's [prior qusetion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75718864/2029983) I would guess that the statement *"`a.text_field` has value `성 이름`"* isn't true, and it actually has the value `? ??`.